Multiple clicks on power button to turn on laptop
I am using thinkpad t560 while using windows it used to turn on in one press of power button, but now it takes around 10 12 clicks of power button to turn it on, I am using latest Ubuntu.

This is a hardware issue and not related to Ubuntu. Please note that some notebooks have a "child" or "cat" :) lock to prevent accidental single click on the power button and sometimes this depends on whether the notebook is plugged in the power or not. Please try single long press to power on your thinkpad.

Pressing the hardware button is not related to the operating system at all. At the time the button is pressed, the operating system is not involved at all. The first thing is the the BIOS/UEFI starts to run, then an OS gets involved. You may want to consider raising your hardware-related question in the Thinkpad Forum or Lenovo's support forum.
